# JIRA JQL - get the work log for a single day

Tags: jira, jql

When I use this JQL

```
worklogDate >= startOfDay(-0d) AND worklogAuthor = currentUser()
```

as a filter in a WorkLog pie chart gadget, it sums *all* of the work hours logged on all tasks that I have been working on this day, while I'm looking for hours logged *only today*.

What can I do to only list the hours that I actually logged today?

Comment: If you want to get a split of all the worklogs, you could use a Chrome extension called **Jira Assistant**. Helpful tool, but if it is via JQL or some, it might get messier!